# How to find out the number of ways to solve Instant Insanity

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Problem :  We are given **4** cubes. The **6** faces of every cube are variously colored - **Blue**, **Green**, **Red** or **White**. Stack the cubes on top of another in such a way that no color appears twice on any of the four sides of this column.
The book says that by a trial-and-error method, a person can try 41,472 ways.
It is given as :  **41,472 = 3 * 24 * 24 * 24** 
 How did they do it? I know that by using proper Permutations and Combinations, one can deduce the number of ways. Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: In Donald Knuth's paper [Estimating the Efficiency of Backtrack Programs](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0373371-6/S0025-5718-1975-0373371-6.pdf) you can find an explanation.

Comment: This is Narsingh Deo's book on Graph theory right?

Comment: @miracle173 that's a great find. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*I am puzzled by the absence of information on how the cubes are actually coloured.*

- *what colour is used for the remaining faces?*
- *are the colours applied the same for all dices (like standard dice have the dots painted in the same relative arrangement)?*
- *how are the colours distributed? Are there all blue cubes?*

*To compensate for this lack of information, I came up with this story:*

---

Assuming that we use a simple bot without camera to perform the manual labour of stacking the dice.

There are 6 ways to choose the front face, times 4 orientations = 24 configurations.

This applies to four cubes and gives
$$
24 \times 24 \times 24 \times 24
$$

trial configurations.

The control mechanism has colour detection, and it inspects only the four sides.

However

- The validity of the pattern along the sides is the same (either matching the criterion or not) if we rotate the column as a whole in one of four ways, 
  reduction by factor 4 is possible.
- The validity of the pattern is the same, if we turn the whole column upside down or not, reduction by factor 2 is possible.

So we would try to provide a software update to the bot, which just tries
$$
3 \times 24 \times 24 \times 24
$$
times and is guaranteed to stack up a valid configuration, if it exists.

---

***Update:*** I found a page about this puzzle [Instant Insanity](http://home.comcast.net/~stegmann/pattern.htm#insanity), the cubes are coloured indeed by $4$ colours applied to the 6 faces. It turns out that the $4^6 = 4096$ ways to colour $6$ faces with $4$ colours reduce to $240$ possibilites if one considers rotations. ([Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)) The producers of this puzzle pick a specific set of $4$ out of the $240$ possible cubes which has exact one solution.

Comment: But one may also swap the top two dice, or the second upper with the bottommost, while keeping their spatial orientation, generally any dice positions' permutation gives the same result! (Unless 'a color appears twice' means 'twice in a row', that is on adjacent dice faces...)

Comment: @mvw , this may help you with how the colors are distributed - 
http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/insanity.htm

Comment: @Sidsec9 Thanks a lot! They apply the puzzle-as-a-whole symmetry as well, to reduce by $8$. Phew. But I still don't see why the $4!$ reduction of interchanging the cubes, which CiaPan pointed out does not apply. At that linked page they first add it, and then take it away. Hm..

Comment: @CiaPan The link from Sidsec9 shows that we have four distinguishable dice. While it doesn't matter for the criterion, it does not allow to reduce the configurations by $4!$.

Comment: @mvw You're right, each $24$ term represents a single die orientation, but has nothing to do with its position in a column, so there's no permutation coefficient to reduce. Sorry, I have commented too soon, did not consider things deep enough.

Comment: @CiaPan No excuse, I found it a valid point to raise.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently was wondering about the same problem and came across your thread. Many thanks for posting this. It's a really interesting problem because it seems as though it should be simple, but isn't at all obvious how to perform this calculation: likewise, the apparent simplicity but fiendish difficulty of this puzzle explains why it's been so popular for over 50 years! I'm sorry I don't have an answer, but I can contribute the following information which might help.

For brevity, I'm using C1 to C4 to indicate each of the four cubes, with lower case {f,b,t,u,l,r} to indicate the faces {Front, Back, Top, Underside (= bottom), Left, Right} ; and {R,Y,G,B,V,W} to indicate 6 different possible colours {Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Violet, White}. There's probably a better standard notation out there: if so please let me know.

1) Consider C1. Colour the front of it Red. Choose a second colour for the opposite face, e.g. Blue.  i.e. C1f = R, C1b = B. The remaining 4 colours must now be permuted around the remaining faces (t,u,l,r), You'd expect 4! = 24 permutations, but in fact it is 4!/4 = 6 permutations if we divide by 4 to account for symmetrical patterns (? 4-fold rotation of each square face) which produce the same end result. If we keep C1f = R, but choose each of the 5 colours (B,G,Y,V,W) in turn for C1b, there are again going to be 6 distinct ways in which the remaining 4 faces can be coloured using the remaining 4 colours in each case. i.e. there will be 5 * 6 = 30 distinct ways in which one cube can be painted using 6 different colours, one colour per face. (Bonus points if you can work out how many distinct ways one cube can be painted using a choice of 7 colours, one colour per face!).
(Adapted from: Askew M, Ebbutt S. The Bedside Book of Geometry. New Burlington Books, London: 80-81).

So you might naively expect the number of combinations of the 4 cubes used in Instant Insanity to be 30^4 = 810,000; however this figure must be reduced to take into account the additional constraints that: a) the cubes do not have to be placed in order C1 to C4, so there is some symmetry in the sequence of cubes; b) we are not interested in the sides of the cubes: the sides of adjacent cubes are touching and not visible, and the ends are not visible in the completed puzzle; c) Instant Insanity only uses 4 colours, not 6 colours, to colour all 6 faces of each of the 4 cubes. Consequently every cube has either 2 instances of two colours, or 3 instances of one colour.

2) The actual face colours and arrangements of the 4 cubes (make a set yourself!) are:
In order {b,t,f,u,l,r}:
C1: {G,B,Y,G,R,R},
C2: {R,B,Y,G,Y,Y},
C3: {G,B,Y,R,Y,B},
C4: {R,B,Y,R,B,G}.

Ivars Peterson gives a really neat solution to the puzzle using graph theory - you can solve it in 5 minutes!:
http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/MATCH/InstantInsanity/NOTES/InstantInsanitySolutionPeterson.pdf

How to combine the above information with the rest of the thread to come up with the answer 3 * 24 * 24 * 24 = 41,472 is beyond my high school level maths skills; but if anyone can explain step by step where this calculation comes from, I'd be really keen to learn.
Best wishes,
Dave.